# Relations in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am a little confused about this.

Let me put into an example. Let's say I have a table called **books**

```
   {
    "books": {
        "id": 1,
        "bookshelf_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2015-10-26 08:26:32",
        "updated_at": "2015-10-26 08:26:32"
    }
```

And let's say I have another table called **bookshelves**

which has this.

```
"bookshelves": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mrs. Maritza Pollich DVM",
    "slots": 20,

}
```

And this is how the model looks like

**book**

```
public function bookShelf()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\BookShelf');
    }
```

**bookshelf**

```
public function book()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Book');
}
```

Now this works just fine

**The problem**

A `bookshelf` has also many `books` in it as well. How Can achieve this relation(s)?

something like this will cause confusion, I assume.

**Bookshelf** model

```
public function book()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Book');
}
```

and **book** model

```
 public function bookshelf()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Bookshelf');
    }
```

Is this the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second way is right.

each book doesn't have one book shelf individually. so,

Book

```
 public function bookshelf()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Bookshelf');
    }
```

and of course a bookshelf doesn't belong to a single book